# No VPN inside Ubuntu VM?

Tags: vpn, virtualization

Symptom: neither OpenVPN nor wireguard based VPNs work inside Ubuntu VM. Errors range from no network to connection failed, etc. Tried TCP and UDP protocols. Also tried protonvpn and surfshark commercial VPNs.

Host: Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64
LXD VM Guest: Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64

The guest was created with: lxc launch images:ubuntu/jammy/desktop vpntest --vm -c limits.cpu=4 -c limits.memory=8GiB -d root,size=128GB

Additionally I tried creating an empty VM and installing Ubuntu via ISO with the same non-working setup.

Interestingly, VPNs work fine on:

- the host (Ubuntu 22.04)
- a Windows 11 guest in an LXD VM on the same machine.
- a Debian 12 guest in an LXD VM on the same machine.

Seems to be specific to Ubuntu inside the VM - perhaps they are detecting they are a guest and doing something incompatible to the network stack?

Comment: "*Errors range from no network to connection failed, etc*" Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494638/edit) to show complete actual output. Approximations or summaries lack vital details.

Comment: openvpn and wireguard should work fine in VM's.  How is the network between the host and the VM setup, and how does it route to the outside world?  I would suggest you are missing a route somewhere, most likely a return route back to the vm's, and or a nat translating entry.

Comment: The network is the default bridge created by lxd:
| lxdbr0          | bridge   | YES     | 10.116.67.1/24 | fd42:546e:756e:a397::1/64 |             | 21      | CREATED |

Comment: config:
  ipv4.address: 10.116.67.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: fd42:546e:756e:a397::1/64
  ipv6.nat: "true"
description: ""
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
used_by:
<snipped for length>
- /1.0/profiles/default
managed: true
status: Created
locations:
- none